# Sum of elements, per single column and per single row, in 2D array (or table), prints out unexpected values (in C)

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, addition

I'm using Atom editor (1.24.0 x64), with gpp-compiler (3.0.7, GCC in MinGW). Is there any other additional useful information I can add here about the system environment? By the way, I only have one semester in programming, so I don't know how to debug yet.

## Introduction to the problem

I'm trying to sum up the values in a table generated using a 2d array. There are 3 sums in one double while loop. The executed sums are:

1. All elements in the table are added up. No problem here.
2. All elements in the same row are added up. Problem here. The returned values are different than the expected. They are different in value and what I think is memory garbage.
3. All elements in the same column are added up. Problem here too. Same problem as above.

What I expect are the correct values, of course. I really don't know where's the problem. I've already tried different approaches. I can't think on anything more that changing some loops here and there or printing the results to see how the loops are behaving. When I print out the results for the columns and the rows what I've got is what I think are the memory addresses (6487568, etc.).

## Results and expected results

Here you can see the results:

```
2       3       4
5       8       0
7       5       6

The sum of every element in the chart is: 40

The sum of every element per row is:

8                   //Should add up to 9
12                  //Should add up to 13
4200743             //Should add up to  18

The sum of every element per column is:
15      16      4200611

//Should add up to:
//14      16      10
```

## Code

The problem I think is somewere here:

```
/*This sums up the the elements, for the entire table,
for every single row and for every single column.*/
while (row < ROWS)
{
   column = 0;
   while (column < COLUMNS)
   {
        sum += array[row][column];
        sumRow[row] += array[row][column];
        sumColumn[column] += array[row][column];
        column++;
   }
   row++;
}
```

Here's the full [code](https://repl.it/repls/arraysum536278). For some reason the online compiler is not returning the expected result of 40 when adding all the elements, but 29. And the other results are also different.

I've tried the additional approches unsucessfuly:

```
sum += array[row][column];
sumRow[row][COLUMNS+1] += array[row][column];
sumColumn[ROWS+1][column] += array[row][column];
```

Another:

```
sum += array[row][column];
sumRow[row] += array[row][column];
sumColumn[column] += array[row][column];
```

As a side note: I suspect that it is not allowed to make this type of sum in C, but since I'm just a beginner in programming I really don't know. I've already looked in the internet about if this is possible or not without success.

Comment: please, post a complete example, that can be verified by itself.  You only put code snippets, and don't show how the variables are declared and where.  Only with a complete, compilable example can anybody see what is happening in your code.

Comment: The full code is in the provided link. I thought that the guidelines on how to make questions required snippets of code and not the full code. I haven't added the variable's declaration because I didn't think they were necessary to understand the problem. Look for the complete code in the link and tell me if the declaration of variables was or not necessary for the question. I will add them if you think the same after watching the code.

Comment: You need to read _How to post_ help page, it will show you that that's not polite in SO.

Comment: @LuisColorado What's not polite in SO? Be specific, please. I'm still learning how to better post a communicate on this site.

Comment: I mean, what you mean when you wrote "that's not polite".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an array or matrix is created their elements have a random value. And `sumRow[row] += array[row][column];` in first iteration sumRow[row] can non-zero value before summation. So initialize it with zero and it should run fine. Same case with ones too.

Comment: This solution worked. The arrays just needed to be initialized to zero. What I wrote for this program was: `sumColumn[3] = {0}, sumRow[3] = {0};` After this the program worked correctly. But I still can see some strange values in the console when printing out intermediate results (like: 6487568, 6487584). Any idea what those are?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you forgot to initialize with zeroes the arrays `sumRow` and `sumColumn`.

If the arrays are not Variable Length Arrays then you can initialize them when they are declared. For example

```
enum { ROWS = 3, COLUMNS = 3 };
int sumRow[ROWS] = { 0 };
int sumColumn[COLUMNS] = { 0 };
```

Take into account that for accumulators it is better to use the type `long long int` instead of `int`,

For example

```
enum { ROWS = 3, COLUMNS = 3 };
long long int sumRow[ROWS] = { 0 };
long long int sumColumn[COLUMNS] = { 0 };
```

If the arrays are Variable Length Arrays then you may not initialize them when they are declared. In this case you can use the standard function `memset` declared in the header `<string.h>`.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void output_sums( size_t rows, size_t cols, int a[rows][cols] )
{
    long long int sumRow[rows];
    long long int sumColumn[cols];
    long long int sum = 0;

    size_t i, j;

    memset( sumRow, 0, rows * sizeof( long long int ) );
    memset( sumColumn, 0, cols * sizeof( long long int ) );

    i = 0;
    while ( i < rows)
    {
        j = 0;
        while ( j < cols )
        {
            sum += a[i][j];
            sumRow[i] += a[i][j];
            sumColumn[j] += a[i][j];
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }   

    for ( i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
    {
        for ( j = 0; j < cols; j++ )
        {
            printf( "%d\t", a[i][j] );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    printf( "\nThe sum of every element in the chart is: %lld\n", sum );

    puts( "\nThe sum of every element per row is:" );
    for ( i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%lld\n", sumRow[i] );
    }

    puts( "\nThe sum of every element per column is:" );
    for ( j = 0; j < cols; j++ )
    {
        printf( "%lld\t", sumColumn[j] );
    }
}

#define N   3

int main(void) 
{
    int a[N][N] =
    {
        { 2, 3, 4 },
        { 5, 8, 0 },
        { 7, 5, 6 }     
    };

    output_sums( N, N, a );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
2   3   4   
5   8   0   
7   5   6   

The sum of every element in the chart is: 40

The sum of every element per row is:
9
13
18

The sum of every element per column is:
14  16  10
```

**EDIT:** After you provided a reference to your original code then apart from using non-initialized arrays the size of the arrays are also incorrect:

```
 int sumColumn[2], sumRow[2],
              ^^^        ^^^
```

Try not to use magic numbers. Use instaed named constants.

Comment: What are the ^^^ in the last code you wrote? Is a standard way of indicating how many elements can an array save?

Comment: @CarlosW.Mercado You have three attempts to understand yourself what this mean.:)

Comment: I'm studying in detail the function you've shared. What's the usage of enum and memset() here? I'm just starting to understand their functioning.

Comment: What you mean with "magic numbers" at the end of your answer?

Comment: @CarlosW.Mercado enum is used to set constants for the dimensions of the arrays. memset zero-initializes the arrays.

Answer (score 0):

`sumRow` and `sumColumn` are not initialized to zero before you start accumulating sums in them
`memset()` these variables to all zeros before using them